# Keeping references to `IDisposable` when using the Reactive Extensions for .NET: always, never, or sometimes?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, idisposable, system.reactive

Up until now I have zealously kept every reference to the `IDisposable` returned from any `.Subscribe(...)`, `.Connect(...)`, etc, method within Rx. I've done this because of my fear that a garbage collections will dispose the disposable if I don't keep the reference.

However, I did a test in LINQPad where I did some calls `GC.Collect()` on a `.Subscribe(...)` where I didn't keep the reference and guess what? The world didn't end and the subscription ran to completion.

In further testing I found that my subscription was disposed of immediately after `.OnComplete()` without my intervention.

This leads me to understand that, at least for `.Subscribe(...)`, that the only reason to keep a reference to the subscription is to force the subscription to end before its normal completion. It's more like a cancellation token.

So are all Rx disposables used for cancelling rather than keeping alive?

What, then, are the rules for hanging on to an `IDisposable`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `IDisposable` returned by `IScheduler.Schedule()` is only useful if you want to cancel the scheduled action (that is, *before* it's happened)

The `IDisposable` returned by `IObservable.Subscribe` and `IConnectableObservable.Connect` are equivalent, in that disposing either will terminate the subscription to the source observable.

As for garbage collection, while Rx makes it a little more difficult to gauge, it's still bound by the rules of the GC. If the source of your observable is rooted (like the event of a UI control), then you don't need to worry about it being GC'd.

If your source is a `Observable.Interval` or something else is basically a recursive `IScheduler` call, then the scheduler should keep it alive (ie. the thread pool, task pool, or dispatcher) since the observable is rooted to the scheduler (via `IScheduler.Schedule`).

Answer (score 18):

No need to hold on to the IDisposable objects unless you want to unsubscribe from an observable source in the future. Similar for the Schedule methods on IScheduler, whose returned IDisposable objects can be used to cancel the scheduled action.

The garbage collector doesn't care about IDisposable object directly, nor do we implement finalizers on any of our objects, so basically lifetime management of subscriptions etc. is entirely up to you in the world of Rx. Compare it to Win32 handles if you want, with Dispose being the moral equivalent to CloseHandle.

Trivia: at some point during the design of Rx, the cancelable operations returned an Action whose invocation would cause the cancellation. Quite functionally inspired in nature, but less obvious to some. So, we decided to go with an interface that already represents a notion of resource management, and IDisposable was the obvious choice. This said, it departs a little from typical usage of the interface elsewhere in the .NET Framework:

- You'll often just drop the IDisposable object on the floor, in particular for infinite sequences you never unsubscribe from.
- In most cases, you won't use the using statement for Rx IDisposable objects, due to the inherent asynchronous nature of the framework.

Hope this helps,

-Bart (Rx team)

Comment: Suppose I hold on to the returned IDisposable from a source.Subscribe(). If my intention is for 'source' to be GC'ed after its purpose has been fulfilled, but I still hold a reference to the IDisposable, can source be GC'ed?
Also assume that OnCompleted won't be called.

Comment: When I was sketching out a design for an event-subscription interface, I had subscribers supply a predicate via which they could indicate whether they were still interested in the event. When subscriptions were added, some existing subscribers would be checked to see if they were still interested (and dropped if not).  A subscription could thus be held by an object with a `WeakReference` to the thing that was really interested.  Out of curiosity, do you know if such a design was ever considered for any of the MS event-related patterns?

Answer (score 4):

Well, firstly I think its important to point out the garbage collection and disposal of objects / the `IDisposable` interface are completely separate - in particular the garbage collector will never directly dispose of an object by calling the `Dispose` method of an `IDisposable` (unless the finalizer for that object does this itself).

As for when you should hang on to an `IDisposable`, you should maintain a reference to any `IDisposable` object that you need to dispose - it sounds like I'm stating the obvious and thats because I am! :-).  Unless the disposable objects lifetime is longer than a single method the `using` keyword is normally used:

```
using (var myDisposableObject = GetSomeDisposableObject())
{
    myDisposableObject.DoThings();
}
```

This limits the scope of `myDisposableObject` (which helps avoid attempting to use an object that has been disposed) and ensures that the object is correctly disposed of even if an exception is thrown.

It **may** be that for a certain class / API you don't need to (or shouldn't) dispose of an object that is returned to you, however that is entirely up to the API / class that returned that disposable object.

Comment: This answer was added before the question was edited to place emphasis on the `system.reactive` namespace.  I have little experience in this area and so can't help there but I'll still leave this answer in the hope that it helps explain the distinction between GC and IDisposable.

Comment: I'd highlight the point that if you are done with a reference, call dispose (manually or via using) and release the reference. There's no reason to keep those objects in your graph.

Comment: The question hasn't been edited - the emphasis was on Rx from the start - but I nevertheless appreciate your answer and your decision not to remove it.

Comment: @Enigmativity Oh yeah, looks like I just didn't spot the `system.reactive` tag when I first looked at the question! :-) Anyway, hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, it helped me better understand the general behaviour. I'm still keen to get an Rx specific answer though. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, The `IDisposable`, which is returned from `Subscribe()` is only needed to Unsubscribe(). Of course, the Unsubscribe() call doesn't exist, you would `Dispose()` instead, if needed.

Comment: Do you know if that's the case with all of the Rx methods that return `IDisposable`? Like `IConnectableObservervable.Connect()`, `IScheduler.Schedule(Action)`, etc?